# when I change urlconfig,images does not load in django

Tags: django, url

when I change urlconf my images are not load in the page.

this code is when the images are loaded in the page,"urls.py"

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('<lang>/', home_page),
path('', home_redirect),
path('products/', include('products.urls')),
 ]
```

in this code when the images are not loaded

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('<lang>/', home_page),
path('', home_redirect),
path('<lang>/products/', include('products.urls')),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
# add root static files
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
   document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
# add media static files
  urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
     document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I must mention that my problems does not that showing 404 page..my pages loaded but images in page does not load and show alt text instead of image

in "products.urls.py"

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<category>', ProductsListByCategory),
path('<category>/<product_id>/<product_name>', product_detail),
]
```

and "product_list.html"

```
<img src="{{ product.image.url }}"class="img-fluid img-card " alt=" 
         {{product.name }}">
```

I have no idea for solve it...

Comment: `media_app.urls`, Does this app have your media urls?

Comment: yes,my problems in products app.

Comment: Wherever you have added `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` shift it to the project level url patterns.

Comment: i have added ' static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)'i am using images whole project..my problem does not working with staticfiles

Comment: To which url patterns? `media_app`'s url patterns? Shift them to these url pattern.

Comment: products app url pattern..when i am using <lang> variable to url images in product list page are not loaded and when i delete <lang> and load again, images appeares

Comment: Can you show your urls in products app and the part in the template where images are not showing.

Comment: yes now I am Updating my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your url pattern `'<lang>/<category>'` is catching all your media urls. Django uses the first url pattern that matches a url. Change how you are adding your media urls to this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # add root static files
    urlpatterns = static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + urlpatterns
    # add media static files
    urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + urlpatterns
```

This will make it so your media and static urls are at the start of your list of urlpatterns, so no other pattern would catch them first.

Comment: I updated my question because I feel you don't understand my problem